# Probability my results are due to chance

Tags: statistics

I'm just in about to hand in my dissertation and I wondered if I could get some help on a statistical anaylsis I want to put in. So essentially I have 2 96-well plates each filled with a substrate, that if is positive changes colour, on my results 2 of the wells on each plate came up positive in the same places (this is expected as plates are duplicates of each other). But what I wanted to know is what is the probablitity that these results are due to chance? Becasue I realised its not just as simple as 1/96 for each etc.

Would be really grateful for any help!!
Thanks Joe

Answer (score 0):

Under the null hypothesis of independence between experiments, you can look at each experiment as a product of Bernoulli trials with $p = 2/96$ for success for each well. You are given that two wells came up positive on the first experiment, and now you want to know the probability that those two wells are exactly the wells that came up positive for the second experiment. This is $(2/96)^2(94/96)^{94}$ under the null hypothesis of independence of experiments, which is pretty small. If you like, rather than using $p=2/96$ as the estimate for your Bernoulli trial parameter, you can use the $95\%$ confidence level upper bound by using the so-called Wilson's confidence interval (details available on the binomial distribution page on wikipedia). This will give you a p-value of $p^2(1-p)^{94}$ where $p > 2/96$, where $p$ is the upper bound on the binomial distribution parameter, but it shouldn't change your estimate much for the p-value.